# ransack search in spree ignoring true/false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, ransack

I am trying to find all variants in spree where `is_master` is `false` but ransack is not working as expected. The reason I am using ransack is so I can run this search over the spree api so I can make a request like `/api/v1/variants?q[is_master_true]='0'` to get all the non master variants.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#false)

```
>> User.ransack(awesome_false: '1').result.to_sql
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."awesome" = 'f')
```

In practice

```
> Spree::Variant.ransack(is_master_false: '1').result.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"spree_variants\".* FROM \"spree_variants\" WHERE \"spree_variants\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL"
```

The `is_master_false` is ignored in the sql

Another search like `sku_eq` works fine

```
> Spree::Variant.ransack(sku_eq: '17636').result.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"spree_variants\".* FROM \"spree_variants\" WHERE \"spree_variants\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND \"spree_variants\".\"sku\" = '17636'"
```

Why does `is_master_false: '1'` do nothing to the sql query created instead of finding records where `is_master = false`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Why does is_master_false get ignored instead of creating a query that finds all the records where is_maser = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Qwertie:  For ransack search you need to first whitelist all the attributes on which you want to perform ransack search.

Currently, in the [Variant model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/variant.rb#L90) only **weight sku** are whitelisted.

So you need to whitelist **is_master** field yourself

For doing just create a decorator for variant in spree/models with name variant_decorator.rb and write

```
Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  ### WHITELISTED ATTRIBUTES ###
  self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes |= ['is_master']
end
```

Or in spree.rb
add `Spree::Variant.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes.push('is_master')`

Now restart your server or rails console and try it out.

Comment: Thats fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to help you.